# WebStorm light theme still shows dark menu

Tags: webstorm

I am using the version of WebStorm,  2018.1
When I try to set the look&feel from Darcula to a light appearance, it does not completely do that. Some parts of the UI stick to the dark theme.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **Material Theme UI plugin** right?

It sets own GUI Theme in some another way (overrides stuff on the go?). You have to **disable the plugin first** and restart IDE. After that you can use bundled GUI Themes.

That's how it worked before .. so must still work the same even now.

Comment: [Similar issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000327330-Bright-color-schemes-for-appereance-don-t-work) -- the same solution.